# How do I hide large comments that is already commented out?

Tags: texshop, code-folding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{comment}

        lots of stuff here

\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to "hide" or minimise the entire comment environment in the editor? I have a huge document and it becomes a pain scrolling stuff that I commented out. I would like a similar feature as the MatLab editor.

**EDIT** I use TexShop on Mac

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Rather than posting code snippets it is easier to help you if you give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: This is really a question about your editor. For example, using vim I can "fold" comment blocks so that I don't see them unless I want to. As you have not said what editor you are using it will be difficult to help you (and the question may well be better directed to a forum for your editor and hence be off-topic for TeX.SX).

Comment: @Andrew, well that is my minimal working example since this is all I require. But sure...

Comment: @Andrew, I use TexShop, it's what all Mac users use

Comment: Jacob, minimal working examples should compile and yours doesn't. For example, what package defines the `comment` environment? In this question it is perhaps not so important, but the editor that you use is. Btw, I am a mac user and I *do not* use TeXShop:)  - and in any case your question doesn't mention your operating system.

Comment: @Andrew, it is the comment package. It should compile now.

Comment: @jacobsmith - Some MacTeX users use TeXworks, LaTeXian, and a few other front-ends...

Comment: I think we've witnessed the birth of the "meta-comment"! ... Something that can comment out comments.

Comment: There are [several](https://sourceforge.net/p/texshop/feature-requests/16/) [feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/texshop/feature-requests/44/) [requests](https://sourceforge.net/p/texshop/feature-requests/115/) for code folding in TeXShop but they don't seem to have been implemented.

Comment: You either need to switch editor or to not fold code. I guess a third option would be to modify TeXShop to do what you want, but that would arguably be a special case of the first option i.e. a different editor.